# Maximizing a function with dependent variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, first-order-logic, hessian-matrix

I am trying to find the maximum of a function $f(x,y)$ in which $x$ and $y$ are dependent on each other. For example, $x$ is the size and $y$ is the weight of a component.

In order to find the maximum value of this unconstrained optimization problem, first I need to make sure that the function $f$ is jointly concave with respect to $(x,y)$. When I compute the Hessian matrix of $f(x,y)$, my function is not jointly concave because decision variables are dependent.

Can anyone provide me a recommendation on how can I find the optimal value of this function?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to solve for one in terms of the other from your constraints. In other words, if $y=y(x)$ then
$$
f(x,y) = f(x,y(x))
$$
which is now an ordinary function of one variable.

Alternatively, you can look for optima even in non-jointly-concave functions, just it is a little trickier to find *global* optima that way...

Comment: Thanks. I have the explicit form of "f function" but I don't have the explicit relation between x and y. So I computation, I just consider their relation as y=y(x) and therefore in maximizing f(x,y(x)), I am not sure the function f is concave so that I could apply the first-order condition. Any recommendation in this case?

Comment: @Soodi if you don't know an explicit $y=y(x)$, you are doing numerical optimization? To get global optima, try restarting in different parts of the search space. Also if given $x$ you can figure out $y$, that's all you need for a numerical optimizer...